# AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.dialects' has no attribute 'postgresql'

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I was creating a very basic python program connecting it with database in psql.

My code is as following:

---

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine=create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://sidrules:password@localhost:5432/first")

db=scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():

```
 flights=db.execute("select origin, destination, duration from flights").fetchall()

      for flight in flights:

           print(f"from {flight.origin} to {flight.destination} in {flight.duration} min")
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
main()
```

---

while running the above code I am getting following error  (Sorry for strange formatting):

---

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "select.py", line 6, in 
    engine=create_engine("postgres+psycopg2://sidrules:secret@localhost:5432/first")
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py", line 479, in
create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 61, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 172, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 253, in load
    loader = self.auto_fn(name)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects__init__.py", line 45, in _auto_fn
    module = **import**("sqlalchemy.dialects.%s" % (dialect,)).dialects
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql__init__.py",
line 8, in 
    from . import base
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\base.py", line 954, in 
    from uuid import UUID as _python_UUID  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\uuid.py", line 57, in 
    _AIX     = platform.system() == 'AIX'
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\platform.py", line 891, in system
    return uname().system
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\platform.py", line 779, in uname
    node = _node()
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\platform.py", line 582, in _node
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 52, in 
    import os, sys, io, selectors
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\selectors.py", line 12, in 
    import select
  File "D:\HTML\SQL\select.py", line 6, in 
    engine=create_engine("postgres+psycopg2://sidrules:sidhhant@localhost:5432/first")
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py", line 479, in
create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 61, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 172, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 253, in load
    loader = self.auto_fn(name)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects__init__.py", line 49, in _auto_fn

module = getattr(module, dialect)

AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.dialects' has no attribute 'postgresql'*

---

of which I think the last line has to worry about:

---

AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.dialects' has no attribute 'postgresql'

---

Thank you, for your help.

Sorry, for strange format, it's my first question.

Comment: `postgres+psycopg2` -> `postgresql+psycopg2`

Comment: That's giving the exactly same error. Infact earlier i used it and changed it after having error.

Comment: The latter is the correct form, though.

Comment: Okay, I editted my question accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thankyou, to everyone who had seen and thought about my question.

The only problem I had is that the name of my file was 'select.py'.
I don't know how but renaming the file did the trick for me.

Comment: maybe it was a conflicting name with the lib or something